# opnet simulator

Tags: simulation

I have opnet 14.5 I am trying to find a Mobile Node with dual interfaces one for 802.11e (WLAN) and the other for 802.16e (Wimax) but it seems it is not there do opnet 14.5 has this node if no do I need special License ?.
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I would build a custom mode using OPNET Modeler with both interfaces in the model.  You will have to design the connections and rules.  Is it supposed to be a crossbanding relay or bridge or is it supposed to be a single endpoint node (like a computer) that acts as a source and sink only?  Those are the questions you need to consider.  If the latter case and you have a wired+wireless model, you might try replacing the wired interface with a WiMax interface, resulting in two transmitter/receiver pairs (WiMAX vs. WLAN).  I'm not sure about the licensing (you will probably need Modeler + their wireless license among their plethora of license types), but I'm sure Riverbed/OPNET customer service will be happy to assist.